# Can I upload or post a pic of a circuit or schematic to a question

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

How do I add a picture of my circuit or schematic to my question?

Comment: Related: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2671/images-for-new-users

Answer (score 2):

While editing your question (or answer), click on the icon that looks like a tiny mountain range, or hit control-G on your keyboard. You'll get a dialog that allows you to drag-and-drop an image, or enter a URL.

The image will be copied to imgur.com and a properly-formatted link to it inserted into your post.

For schematic diagrams specifically, you can also hit control-M on your keyboard to bring up the CircuitLab editing and simulation tool.

Comment: Dave, you forgot the obvious. Rep cap for new user image posting.

Comment: @Passerby I think that was removed some time in the past year or so, for example [this question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/224883/differential-op-amp-circuit-gain-calculation) was posted by a 1 rep user.